# Creating continuous data UPDATES/INSERTS - SQL Simulation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a bit of side-project on the go that involves creating a simulation of sorts in MSSQL.

The 1000 Mile overview is that it creates a number of "Towns/Cities" with a set population, and then will expand its population based on a number of factors. This would be with Towns/Cities having their own rows within a Cities table. Then a citizen table that would have ever increasing rows. One further table that would marry the Cities to the Citizens. There's a great deal more than that, but that's the basis of the project.

This is largely to experiment with a number of features that I don't get to play with in my day to day work and also just out of interest in the project.

My question is that the project will involve a continuous update to a large number of tables that would need to be automated. Is it feasible that this could be done by just initiating a number of Stored procedures that cycle, or would it be better to create a small application that sits external to the database that writes to the database.

Does anyone have any examples or opinions on the matter that might help. Are there existing software solutions that would allow me to automate these updates, or would keeping it entirely within the database with a series of stored procs be the best option?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect task for SSIS (Integration Services) to me. Did you give it a look already? Might be worth a try...

Comment: The nature of your experimentation isn't clear, but if if involves variation in the factors that affect population growth rate, then consider writing that information into a configuration file and using an external application that will read your experimental parameters from that file (and re-read it whenever the file changes).

Answer (score 1):

Look at [SQL Server's scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439(v=sql.105).aspx). It's pretty intuitive and should do the trick.